# how to calculate name, date and time of zip file in winhex?

Tags: date, zip, hex, docx

how do I calculate the time date and name of a zip file?

I have tried the zip structure but the name of the file is of inside the zip file.

Comment: So, you are interested in the names and time stamps of entries **within** the zip file and not of the zip file itself?

Comment: yes, I am interested in the names and time stamps of entries within the zip file. will you help me with this?

Comment: A way is the Zip-Ada open-source library @ https://unzip-ada.sourceforge.io/ , check for "Traverse_verbose", this will list date&time, name, crc32, sizes and other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For knowing and browsing the zip structure, google for "appnote.txt".

Comment: does the structure of .docx and zip are the same?

Comment: A .docx is a zip file with specific contents.